# How to set "certain time period" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean-logic

```
class CreateGrounddetails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :grounddetails do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :working_hours
      t.string :address
      t.string :contact_no
      t.string :email
      t.integer :no_of_ground
      t.text :description
      t.boolean :featured_ground #featured
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I am able to fetch `true` value from `featured_ground` but I am having problem setting some time period for that featured ground. For e.g scheduling `featured_ground` to true must feature that specific ground for certain time period and should be automatically set to false after that time period.

Comment: There is some context missing. You could do this in your controller or model.

Comment: Or you can set "cronjob" for this, ie. update values in database field after certain period of time. look into this link https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 2):

Can set "Cronjob" in application and run after specific period of time.
Please go through following link where you can find solution about how to set it with "whenever" gem.

https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace the boolean `featured_ground` field with a timestamp `featured_at` field? That way you can see if the ground was featured within a period of time.